# How to target input value inside a class (CSS)?

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

So, people, I have one image gallery with filters and I have a problem targeting the input value.
Everything works when input radio buttons are not inside a  but since I added that class, I cannot  get it to work. You can see on Codepen, line 41 and below where the comment "Targeting of values" is, how the values were targeted before adding of div with .filters class. How are the values supposed to be targeted/selected now?

[Codepen: How to target input value inside a class (CSS)?](https://codepen.io/abudimir/pen/qBNWdvm)

```
<div class="filters">
<!-- Filters -->
<input type="radio" name="categories" id="all" value="all" checked>
<input type="radio" name="categories" id="branding" value="branding">
<input type="radio" name="categories" id="graphical" value="graphical">
<input type="radio" name="categories" id="interior" value="interior">
<input type="radio" name="categories" id="illustrations" value="illustrations">
<input type="radio" name="categories" id="arts" value="arts">

<ol class="filter-items">
<li><label for="all">All</label></li>
<li><label for="branding">Branding</label></li>
<li><label for="graphical">Graphical Design</label></li>
<li><label for="interior">Interior Design</label></li>
<li><label for="illustrations">Illustrations</label></li>
<li><label for="arts">Arts</label></li>
</ol>
</div>

<!-- Gallery -->
<div class="grid-gallery">
<div class="photo">image 1</div>
<div class="photo">image 1</div>
</div>

<style>
input[type="radio"] {
display: none;
}


[value="all"]:checked ~ .grid-gallery [data-category] {
display: block;
}

<!-- Targeting of values -->
[value="branding"]:checked ~ .grid-gallery .photo:not([data-category~="branding"]),
[value="graphical"]:checked ~ .grid-gallery .photo:not([data-category~="graphical"]),
[value="interior"]:checked ~ .grid-gallery .photo:not([data-category~="interior"]),
[value="illustrations"]:checked ~ .grid-gallery .photo:not([data-category~="illustrations"]),
[value="arts"]:checked ~ .grid-gallery .photo:not([data-category~="arts"]) {
  display: none;
}
 </style>
```

Comment: Your html is missing the data-category attribute or is it not in real ?

Comment: It's there on Codepen but it's not present here.
That aside, my problem is that I simply don't know the syntax for calling the value. When Ii remove the div .filters, everything works.

Comment: input radios needs to be a **sibbling** of & ahead `.grid-gallery` so CSS can do it. if you keep the radio inside `.filters`, javascript will be required because CSS has no parent selectors. https://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/vYKByae reminds me of an old test of mine : https://codepen.io/gcyrillus/pen/JFdEk

Comment: I get it now. :)
You're correct. Thank you.

Comment: @G-Cyrillus, can you write it as an answer so I can accept it? Maybe someone else will find it useful too.